# Freeze during boot Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, startup, 20.04

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to my two laptops (Lenovo X230 and T420s) and in both of them I occasionally experience a freeze during the startup. Does anybody know what's wrong with Ubuntu's new release? And that how can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Uninstalling Nvidia drivers and installing them again helps.

1) Add PPA repository with beta drivers at the risk of an unstable system:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

2) Install all recommended drivers automatically:

```
 sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Comment: Pressing `esc` when the logo appears also helps.